# Squishing an image from above in Sony Vegas Pro 18

Tags: video, video-editor, editing, vegas-pro, keyframes

I am using Sony Vegas 18.

I am attempting to squish an image from above, keeping the width and bottom x, y coordinates fully fixed, meaning the image "squishes" while being reducing in the y dimension over time.

Please see this crude image of what I would like to achieve. The orange box is the image I would like to squish with the red arrow indicating from where I want to reduction to take place.

[image: Example]

I have attempted to achieve this with the pan/crop tool but it does not provide me with the means to do so. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Create two keyframes, the first with your original size, the second with the cropped size. You should turn off fixed aspect ratio for your case.